# How can I select all cells that contain specific text in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, formatting

I have a spreadsheet that contains 20,000 cells.

I want to select all cells that contain "foobar". In other words, I want to highlight them so that they can be copied, formatted, etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "select" and why do you need to select them ?

Comment: @PaulJ - Select them as in highlight them so that they can be copied, formatted, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If "foobar" is all in one column, I think a simple solution would be to create a filter, then click the dropdown to select foobar.

Check out the section titled "Filter your data" on this link https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is a solution involving a workaround with a simple script.

First you want to copy the below formula next to every row in your sheet.
This will fetch all cell addresses containing "foobar" on this row.

```
=REGEXREPLACE("'"&join("', '",Arrayformula(if(A2:F2="foobar",address(row(), COLUMN(A2:F2)), "X")))&"'","'X', |'X'","")
```

Then you want to put all the addresses in one string using the below formula.

```
=CONCATENATE(G2:G)
```

The next step is to paste this string into a selection script like this:

```
function foobar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRangeList(['$A$3', '$B$6', '$A$9', '$B$9', '$E$9', '$A$13', '$B$13', '$C$13', '$D$13', '$E$13', '$F$13']).activate();
};
```

Once you go back to the sheet and run the script it will select all cells containing "foobar"

[This is the link to the example.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LnWmCjFyoJ2czhm0bES6q-QH7cVo-xQlle5V6pduIL8/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically select cells that contain the word or phrase you enter in a magic cell by installing the [quickFind_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67555531/13045193) script. Please try this code:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.');
  }
  quickFind_(e);
}

/**
* Finds cells that match the regular expression entered in a magic cell.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function quickFind_(e) {
  const sheets = /^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i; // use /./i to make the function work in all sheets
  const magicCell = 'A1';
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!e.value
    || e.range.getA1Notation() !== magicCell
    || !sheet.getName().match(sheets)) {
    return;
  }
  let searchFor;
  try {
    searchFor = new RegExp(e.value, 'i');
  } catch (error) {
    searchFor = e.value.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
  }
  const magicCellR1C1 = 'R' + e.range.rowStart + 'C' + e.range.columnStart;
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const matches = [];
  data
    .forEach((row, rowIndex) => row
      .forEach((value, columnIndex) => {
        if (value.match(searchFor)) {
          const cellR1C1 = 'R' + (rowIndex + 1) + 'C' + (columnIndex + 1);
          if (cellR1C1 !== magicCellR1C1) {
            matches.push(cellR1C1);
          }
        }
      }));
  if (matches.length) {
    sheet.getRangeList(matches).activate();
  }
}
```

The function uses a cell of your choice, say `A1`, as the search box. Choose **View > Freeze** to ensure the search box is always visible. Then enter the search string in the search box and press **Tab** to activate matching cells in the active sheet. You can also use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as a search string.

Comment: This is almost a link only answer which are not allowed. Please add the essentials parts of the referred resource or add it as comment to the question.

Comment: @Rubén The link points to a Stack Exchange resource. Copying the code here would seem wasteful. Please advice.

Comment: The rational is that the linked resource might not be available later and that cross-posting answer is allowed and encouraged. For details see [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/289691) and [Is cross-posting an answer to similar questions on different Stacks acceptable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291501/289691)

Comment: Hmm... top voted answer: "It probably is a good idea to cross reference an answer, and try to tailor your answer to the specific site" — no tailoring required here. Nevertheless, edited the answer to include the code verbatim.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you want to search for "foobar" in the `A1:B10` range.

Use a IF formula with a condition based on `=REGEXMATCH` :

`IF` the range contains "foobar", return the cell, else we do nothing. You can return the cell data but also coordonnate with `=ROW() and =COLUMN()`

You want to test every cells so I made an array with `ArrayFormula`.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(REGEXMATCH(A1:B10;"foobar");A1:B10;))
```

Edit : this method is case-sensitive, space-sensitive, etc... try using `=TRIM` or `=LOWER`

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have interested cell range `B1:B10`. In order to show all cells which contain case insensitive text `"Text2Search"`, try the following:

```
=ArrayFormula(If(IfError(Search("Text2Search",B1:B10),0)>0,B1:B10, "NoMatch"))
```

Note, that `"NoMatch"` can be replaced with any other text or even just empty "".
Hope this help!